# Java's File.pathSeparator in Perl

Tags: perl, path, cross-platform, environment-variables

Is there a module or constant somewhere in Perl that gives the equivalent of Java's [File.pathSeparatorChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar)? I've been looking everywhere but the name easily brings up things like `/` and `\`, used to separate elements in a single path. I want the thing you use to separate values in an environment variable containing paths (`:` in Unix, `;` in Windows, and I have no idea if there are others on other platforms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `$Config{path_sep}`:

```
use Config;
print "path separator for $^O is '$Config{path_sep}'\n";

path separator for cygwin is ':'
```

(I found this be grepping for `split.*PATH` in the perl source code)

Comment: I get this: `path separator for MSWin32 is ''`

Comment: That's a bummer. It works for me ... `perl -MConfig -e "print $^O,' => ',$Config{path_sep}"` --> `MSWin32 => ;`

Comment: ah! Works great, thanks. I would never have thought of grepping the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually *do anything* with the system `PATH` variable, then you probably want the [`Env::Path`](https://metacpan.org/module/Env%3a%3aPath) module, but that indeed gets the value for the separator from `$Config::Config{path_sep}`.

Note that it is cleaner to use the `Config` module as

```
use Config ();
```

and then access the hash using the fully-qualified `%Config::Config`, as otherwise the module silently imports `%Config` into your current namespace.

Comment: Great! I was looking for something like this. In my case, I'm editing CLASSPATH for an `Inline::Java` module.